# Beveled Paths with Collision Physics to Hold in a Weave Pattern

Tags: modeling, physics

I'm trying to create a model using several path strands in a weave pattern that obey collision physics.

Taking beveled lines like this:
[image: Nurb line with bevel shape]

I want to model these into a weave pattern like this:
[image: Wicker cane weave]

How should I go about the physics part of this?

I've tried setting vertex groups at the ends of a meshed version of these shapes, then using Cloth physics, but the collision physics don't seem to work.

I know I could use a bump map shader to get the look of the weave, but I'd really like to model this if possible.

Comment: why exactly are you using physics?

Comment: I'd like to pin vertex groups at each end and of the strands and have tension so the weave can pull together tightly.

Comment: but if you can get the same result without physics?